# Generate or find C headers for ICU core on OSX

Tags: c, macos, osx-mavericks, icu

Unfortunately apple has not included header files for `libicucore` on OSX. Is there any way I can nevertheless use this library? I only need some simple functionality and ICU is too big to bundle with my app. It looks like ICU version 53.1.0 which is fairly recent:

```
jeroen$ otool -L /usr/lib/libicucore.dylib
libicucore.dylib:
    /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 53.1.0)
    /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 120.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1213.0.0)
```

What complicates things is that I have a hard time finding out what is included with the *core* target of ICU. I can use `nm` to manually check if a particular symbol is present in the library:

```
jeroen$ nm /usr/lib/libicucore.dylib | grep ToUpper
00000000000b74c9 T _u_strToUpper
000000000006ff70 T _ucasemap_utf8ToUpper
```

Now I can manually grab the headers for `u_strToUpper` from the 53.1.0 release of ICU, but that is a lot of work. Is there a better way to find or generate the headers for ICU core 53.1.0 on OSX?

Comment: Typically you'd install the development version of a library onto your computer, if you want to write programs using it...

Comment: Apple ships ICU to serve the needs of Core Foundation and Foundation. Is there a reason that you can't use those, which would be the supported way to do these things on OS X? For example, use `CFStringUppercase()` for whatever you'd use those `...ToUpper` functions for.

Comment: I would like to use the same code on Linux/Solaris as Mac.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like my best bet is grabbing the headers from the [apple website](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/ICU/ICU-531.30/). This repository also includes the makefile for `libicucore.dylib` which uses `--with-data-packaging=archive` to put the ICU data tables in a standalone file `/usr/share/icu/icudt51l.dat`.

Answer (score 3):

You can download header files from Apple's or ICU's official websites and link against the system's `libicucore` library. But you can't upload a product to App Store or Mac App Store. It will be immediately rejected as one that uses private API. iTunes Connect has an automatic script that detects such references after you upload a new binary.